# PHP multi-subdomain session not recognized on first page load

Tags: php, session, cookies, subdomain

I have the following:

```
session_name("user_login");
session_set_cookie_params(0,"/",".example.com");
session_start();
```

This should share the $_SESSION array on all subdomains.

I also have some cookies set up like this:

```
setcookie("username",$username,time()+31449600,"/",".example.com");
```

Now the problem: On the subdomain that these are set, everything works fine. Upon visiting another subdomain, it is as if nothing has been set. Nothing is recognized. Doing a `print_r()` of everything comes up blank and tests such as `isset($_SESSION["something_here"])` return false.

**...until I reload the page.** The second visit works perfectly & everything is where it should be.

Going back to the original subdomain exhibits the same behavior *if specific session variables are being altered on both pages* although, if nothing is being changed, both pages work OK after each initial reload/visit such as remembering if a user is logged in.

Can anyone speculate on what's going on?

To fix the problem, I have attempted to add some page refreshes and XMLHttpRequest-inject some session-sensitive code in but, because I can't see the session, I can't properly detect when a refresh will be needed/not needed and XMLHttpRequests from the first-load page come back without the session data also.

Comment: check `session_id()`. if it's different between the two pages, then you have two separate/independent sessions

Comment: `session_id()` is the same on all subdomains. Just double-checked.